# 'ReadOnly Data is modified'

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, readonly

Today I have just got these exclamation marks in two of my `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`s

[image]

When I hover the mouse over it a tooltip pops up saying 'ReadOnly Data is modified'.

The `Datasource` is a `DataTable` that is filled by an SQL query; every other column is fine. I have not seen this before and can't find anything on Google about it either. The `DataGridView` is `ReadOnly` although I have tried making it not `ReadOnly` but the same thing happens.

Just wondering what could be causing this as the data has not been modified at all. It just comes from SQL into a `DataTable` and gets bound to the `DataSource`

The column has a `DataType` of `int`.

Comment: Is that the exact error message, i.e. it actually says "ReadOnlyData" and not "Read-only data" or some other variation?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, it reads "ReadOnly data is modified" I've edited my mistake